# Why am I getting this PHP Mailer language error?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having this Error in PHP:

Language string failed to load: recipients_failed

My Code is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
                $mail->Host = "mail.escentrics.com"; // SMTP server
                $mail->From = "example@escentrics.com";
                $mail->AddAddress($Email);

                $mail->Subject = "Tradeworx Account Confirmation";
                $mail->Body = "Hello $fname,

Account Information:
Username/Email: $email
Password: $password


To activate you account just go to this link: http://192.168.1.101/tradeworx/TWWebsite/index.php?page=Confirmation&id=$userid&confirmationcode=$confirmcode";
                $mail->WordWrap = 100;

                if(!$mail->Send())
                {
                   echo 'Message was not sent.';
                   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                }
                else
                {
                   echo 'Message has been sent.';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that PHPMailer can't find its language translation files for the real error messages. What triggered this is most likely a bad 'To' address, which means that most likely `$Email` is incorrect: blank, mal-formed, etc... Remember that PHP variables are case sensitive, so make sure it's actually `$Email` with a capital E (and contains a valid email address) and not `$email` or similar.

Comment: @Andro, what was the error?  The case for the `$Email` variable or something else?

Comment: its just the variable name. the variable that i should use is $email. Its my bad.